# Is my variable a discrete random variable, ordinal, or categorical?

Tags: categorical-data, continuous-data, discrete-data

I work in trauma research. We use a injury grading system that is fairly unique. Using a system developed in the 60s-70s - the Abbreviated Injury Scale - injuries are graded for six distinct body regions - head, face, chest, abdomen, extremities, and external. The ranges for each region differ a bit with a lower score denoting a minor injury, while a higher score denotes a lethal, non-survivable injury. The ranges of the score vary: 1-4 (face), 1-5 (extremity), and 1-6 (head, chest, abdomen, and external). If a region is uninjured, that region can have a value of zero.

Then an Injury Severity score (ISS) is derived by taking the sum of squares for the three most injured regions. For example, Head = 3, Face = 0, Chest = 5, Abdomen = 0, Extremity = 2, External = 0 -> (3^2) + (5^2) + (2^2) = ISS 38.

A bit more background: The range of ISS is 1-75 (75 being a non-survivable injury). Also, any region with a value of 6 is considered a lethal injury, and is automatically given an ISS of 75.

So I have done the math. Given that the ISS is derived from a sum of squares, I have determined that there are actually 31 integers between 1 and 75 that are not mathematically possible (7, 15, 23, 28, 31, 37, 39, 40, 44, 46, 47, 49, 52, 53, 55, 56, 58, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, and 74). Therefore, there are only 44 integers between 1and 75 that are possible, and they are non-contiguous. That said, ISS is commonly reported in the literature as a continuous variable, despite the  fact that an ISS cannot take on numerous values between 1 and 75.

Should ISS be considered as a discrete random variable given it is a countable value that can only take on a set number of values? However, can it be a discrete random variable if the possible values are non-contiguous (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14... 54, 57, 58...)?

I have read a number of statistics books, and reviewed numerous online resources, but I am still unclear on what kind of variable to call an ISS? Also, to make matters more interesting, is it possible to use it as a continuous variable given the number for "categories"?

Here is a link to one paper that provides a good overview of ISS: https://injuryprevention.bmj.com/content/7/1/10

Comment: Usages vary, which is some of the point here. To me (and to some others too) (1) _Discrete_ just implies a limited set of possible values, so in principle I wouldn't exclude categorical from being discrete, although in practice I would avoid using discrete for categorical variables. (2) Categorical includes ordinal so that it's better to say nominal if you think that any variable is categorical but not ordinal.  Hazardous to guess on majority usage but I guess (2) is widespread in literature and discussion, while (1) avoiding the term discrete for categories is common in practice too.

Comment: It is clearly discrete by forcing the original scores to be integer and then doing calculations which preserve integers.  This is unaffected by some intermediate sums of squares being theoretically being impossible to attain (though there do seem to be a few cases of 7 illustrated in Figure 2).  There is no point trying to "normalise" the data or make it continuous - it gives a number which is supposed to point to relative severity of combined injuries.  If you want continuous results, change the rules, and allow original scores like $1.3$ rather than forcing a choice which is $1$ or $2$

Comment: Minor comment: A basic definition of “discrete random variable” is a random variable that can take only a finite or countably infinite number of possible values. So a random variable X that can take values only in the 3-element set $\{-8.2, 1.3, 6.88\}$ is indeed a “discrete random variable.” Most of the “famous” discrete random variables are non-negative integer valued (such as Geometric, Binomial, Bernoulli, Poisson), but don’t let the famous ones get all the attention! =)  For discrete random variables we work with the PMF P[X=-8.2], P[X=1.3], P[X=6.88], rather than PDF.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful reply. I certainly think it is discrete. That said, is it categorical or a discrete random variable. I ask because if it is a discrete random variable I can still calculate summary statistics such as mean, sd, median, etc. However, if it is categorical, such summary statistics would not be appropriate.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, this is a **discrete variable** that can only take on a finite number of non-negative integer values.  The fact that the support for this variable is on a subset of the values 0-75, excluding some integer values in this range, does not change the fact that it is a discrete variable.

From a statistical perspective, this is not a particularly interesting variable in its own right.  It is formed as a function of an underlying set of ordinal variables and its purpose is to condense them down to a single number for the purpose of encapsulating an overall level of injury.  If the resulting number were intended to be an ordinal measurement, you could remove all the impossible numbers from the outcome scale and reduce it to a shorter integer scale (with no gaps) if this was preferable.  (Obviously that would change the formula used to calculate the score, so it might be considered an inconvenience.)

The question at issue from a statistical perspective would be whether the value obtained by the ISS formula actually reflects a reasonable inference about the ordinal severity of a set of underlying injuries of different parts of the body (as measured with respect to some objective outcome measure).  For example, do different sets of injuries leading to the same ISS score actually have the same severity (e.g., same probability of death, injury, etc.)?  Do different sets of injuries leading to different ISS scores obey the ordinal ranking of the score with respect to severity (e.g., correct ordering for probability of death, injury, etc.)?  The explanation in [Stevenson *et al* (2001)](https://injuryprevention.bmj.com/content/7/1/10) gives an indication of some consideration of these statistical issues, but it is not clear whether the scoring method reflects any actual regression analysis attempting to predict any objective medical outcome for the patient.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful reply. I certainly think it is discrete. That said, is it a categorical variable, or a discrete random variable (DRV). If it is a DRV I can still calculate summary statistics such as mean, sd, median, etc. However, if it is categorical, such summary statistics would not be appropriate (right?). Furthermore, ordinal data is often reported in the literature as continuous (Glasgow Coma Scale), so are there times when it is appropriate to analyze ordinal data as continuous?

Comment: Since the order of the quantity is meaninful, it is not a categorical variable.

Answer (score 10):

To add to @Ben's excellent answer to an excellent question, how you analyze ISS is more important than the nomenclature you choose for its type.  Treating it as an ordinal variable automatically recognizes its discreteness, and results in an efficient analysis that does not assume a specific distributional shape if you use a [semiparametric ordinal response model](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo), the most popular of which is the proportional odds ordinal logistic regression model.  Detailed case studies where ordinal models are applied may be found [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc).  In addition to the discreteness of ISS, it also has floor and ceiling effects which are well handled with ordinal models.

With ordinal semiparametric models it is not necessary that categories be contiguous, so removal of unused levels is not necessary.

From a proportional odds model you can estimate effect ratios (odds ratios), exceedance probabilities, the entire cumulative distribution function, means, and if there are few ties in the data, quantiles such as the median.

Comment: "Treating it as an ordinal variable automatically recognizes its discreteness" Continuous variables can be ordinal.

Comment: Definitely.  I was referring to the fact that ordinal variables are flexible, being discrete, continuous, or mixed as long as ordering is meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should first be noted that ISS is essentially an engineered feature, and one that has been engineered by someone else, for someone else's purposes. If you don't have access to the data it is engineered from, then you are stuck with it, but if you do, then you should consider whether the underlying data is more useful.

Second, there is in some sense no such thing as a continuous variable, unless you're doing data science on an analog computer. Any digital device has a finite number of outputs. The discrete/continuous distinction really comes down to the number of possible states: if you have a handful of states, it's discrete, if you have millions of states, it's continuous. 44 states is a judgment call. I would lean towards treating it as discrete.

As for whether it's ordinal, the connection between intervals and the underlying measured is so indirect that there isn't a clear reason to think it's cardinal, so you should default to ordinal.

But really, these labels are about what helps your model the most, not any transcendent ontological reality. If you're doing hypothesis testing, then what type of variable it is is part of the null hypothesis and thus can play a part in calculating p-values. But for prediction models, if treating it as discrete results in a better model, you should treat it as discrete, and if treating it as continuous results in a better model, you should treat it as continuous. The same goes for ordinal versus cardinal.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful reply. I am still confused though if I can treat it as a discrete random variable; and thus, use summary statistics such as the weighted mean, sd, or median. Or, should it be purely categorical?